# Request to appending more data to existing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please this question is just a request for guide. No coding had been started yet but based on recommendations, I will begin the coding. I am still new to JQuery.

I want to load all my blog posts using JSON API plugin. I have been able to create the code to load the posts and limit it to just 3 posts out of 11 posts.

I just want to know what the best approach or sequence is to add a link so when someone clicks on it, it then looks through the already displayed posts, checks for the last posts and then appends the next 3 posts until all 11 posts had been displayed before it either hides the Load more link or greys it out.

Please I just need someone who had done something similar to this to advise on the sequence to use.

1. Create a Load function to load the first 3 posts and store in a div (id=postcontent)
2. Create a click function that on clicking a class element (.loadmore), checks content of existing div (id=postcontent), does a count, compares the count to total of posts in json data (11), then looks for last post and appends another 3 posts and does a refresh to maintain the markup

Comment: Have you thought of any approach? First tell us how you think you can take this on. Then people will advice you.

Comment: This is my thought process. 1. Create a Load function to load the first 3 posts and store in a div (id=postcontent) 2. Create a click function that on clicking a class element (.loadmore), checks content of existing div (id=postcontent), does a count, compares the count to total of posts in json data (11), then looks for last post and appends another 3 posts and does a refresh to maintain the markup

Comment: I am not sure if its possible to combine all the functions together rather than creating two separate functions

Comment: Are you fetching from a server that you dong control? Does your server return all posts in one request? Or can you modify the server script?

Comment: I am using WordPress with JSON API so its returning all Posts in one request but it can be controlled

Comment: If you load all posts in one go, then you need to either store them in memory (considering they are full posts, then its gonna take a lot!!). or you need to use only 3 from the request and make requests again and again and each time using only 3/11. Thats poor usage of the network. What do you plan to do now?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you have expanded on your question, please edit your question to include that information, as comments are not permanent and could be removed at any time.  Thank you!

Comment: I have added my comment to the post